# Changing index name in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

How can I change the `Unnamed: 0` and the blank header of columns so it would look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change both the names of index and columns axis.

You can do it like this:

```
df.index.name = 'BBID'
df.columns.name = 'VALUE_DATE'
```

or with a chained method like this:

```
df = df.rename_axis('VALUE_DATE').rename_axis('BBID', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'BBID VALUE_DATE'}, inplace=True)
df.set_index('BBID VALUE_DATE' , inplace = True)
```

Comment: you forgot to make the column as index again. One can do it like this df.set_index('BBID VALUE_DATE' , inplace = True)

Comment: Hmm so the BBID is the header for the column names and VALUE_DATE is the header for the row names. They are separate, sorry for being vague in the sc.

Comment: There is no such thing as "header for columns"